# ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4 equivalent to JavaScript 3 next and previous extent?

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to find the JavaScript 4 equivalent to the next extent and previous extent methods discussed in the JavaScript 3 documentation. This link takes you to the page I'm referring to in the documentation for 3. There is no path similar to esri/toolbars/navigation in the documentation for 4 and I can't seem to find it anywhere else.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/navigation-amd.html

Much appreciative!

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box equivalent for the 3x Navigation toolbar in 4x, nor its specific zoomToNextExtent/zoomToPrevExtent methods.  See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/functionality-matrix/#esritoolbars

To replicate those methods you would have to watch for extent changes and keep track of them yourselves:

```
    let extentArray = [];
    // Get the new extent of the view only when view is stationary.
    watchUtils.whenTrue(view, "stationary", function() {
      if (view.extent) {
        extentArray.push(view.extent.clone());
      }
    });
```